# Autofac and generic command pattern

Tags: c#, autofac, command-pattern

I am trying to decorate my command handlers and I am trying to resolve them in my processor.

I registered my command like this:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ICommandProcessor).Assembly)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<,>))
    .AsSelf().AsImplementedInterfaces().Named("implementor", typeof(ICommandHandler<,>));

builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
    typeof(CatchValidationErrorsDecorator<,>),
    typeof(ICommandHandler<,>), fromKey: "implementor")
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

The problem is that when i am not using the Named extension, the generic decorator is not working.
When I use the named extension, I am not able to resolve my components like this:

```
var handerType = typeof (ICommandHandler<,>)
    .MakeGenericType(command.GetType(), typeof (TResult));
dynamic handler = _container.Resolve(handerType);
```

Someone has an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has given me serious headaches in the past. The registration that eventually did it for me was:

```
var assembly = typeof(ICommandProcessor).Assembly);

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).As(type =>
    from interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces()
    where interfaceType.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<,>))
    select new KeyedService("implementor", interfaceType));

builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
    typeof(CatchValidationErrorsDecorator<,>), 
    typeof(ICommandHandler<,>),
    fromKey: "implementor");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That did the trick!
One more question, what if I need to process a command within commands and don't want the commandhandler to be decorated when triggered in another command?

Comment: @Manaus That's something I advise against doing. A command should be an atomic operation and the ICommandHandler a holistic abstraction. You should extract duplicate code into services that you inject into your handlers. Conditionally wrapping your handlers based on the position in the hierarchy is dufficult and error prone, even with other containers.